# Dynamically created java source file not getting refreshed when executing

Tags: java

I am creating a java source file within a program, compiling it and then invoking the main method of the new java class.

```
private static void compileJavaAndExecute(String path, String file)
        throws Exception {
    JavaCompiler compiler = ToolProvider.getSystemJavaCompiler();
    DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
    StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(
            diagnostics, null, null);
    Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager
            .getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList(path + "\\" + file
                    + ".java"));
    JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager,
            diagnostics, null, null, compilationUnits);
    boolean success = task.call();
    URLClassLoader classLoader = URLClassLoader
            .newInstance(new URL[] { new File("D:\\POC\\VoiceAutomation\\src").toURI().toURL() });

    Class.forName("com.test.Test1", true, classLoader)
            .getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class })
            .invoke(null, new Object[] { null });

    fileManager.close();
    System.out.println("Success: " + success);
}
```

This is working fine when i execute the program first time. Now suppose the content of the Test1.java is dynamically generated by my program, I see that it is getting compiled but when the main method gets executed, it is still running the code from the previous run and not the latest code.
Please suggest a fix

Comment: What is 'the previous run'? Does the Java program finish?

Comment: The java program finishes without any errors or exception. To explain the issue with an example, we are dynamically creating the java source code within my program. Say we add a line of code System.out.println("Hello"); and call the above mentioned method , the dynamically created source code will be compiled and main method will be invoked and Hello is printed. In the next run, say we are printing "Hello World" instead of "Hello", the dynamic code is compiled and when the main method gets executed, it still prints "Hello" instead of "Hello World".